# How to encode a tuple inside JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to encode image shape as (4096,2048) in a JSON file, however I am getting the following error --

[image: Traceback]

Not sure if the issue is with the code or the way I am giving values in JSON file.

[image: Input data]

Comment: You might want to post your code as well...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The question needs a cleanup, but here goes --

You used the string `(4096, 2048)` which is not a valid JSON array.

Try `[4096, 2048]` instead.

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("(100,200)") # avoid this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debanjan/PycharmProjects/domain-registrar-service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-78540c75b201>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads("(100,200)")
  File "/home/debanjan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/debanjan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/debanjan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

>>> json.loads("[100,200]") # do this instead
[100, 200]
```